# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.' when upgrading ServiceStack to .netcore 2.0

Tags: .net-core, servicestack, asp.net-core-2.0

We are using ServiceStack(.netcore) as our web services layer, in an open source project yet to go-live. We are planning to migrate to .netcore2.0. We downloaded servicestacks's master branch on Nov 17 from https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack for testing. But we are stuck due to the following exception, servicestack project is not starting up.

We did some research on this and found that .Net Core don't have the toXmlString() and fromXmlString method. Please see https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/874 and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23686.

Need help from the servicestack community.

`$exception  {System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.FromXmlString(String xmlString)
   at ServiceStack.RsaUtils.ToPrivateRSAParameters(String privateKeyXml) in F:\ExpressBase\ExpressBase.Core\ServiceStack.Core\ServiceStack.Client\CryptUtils.cs:line 85
   at ServiceStack.Auth.JwtAuthProviderReader.set_PrivateKeyXml(String value) in F:\ExpressBase\ExpressBase.Core\ServiceStack.Core\ServiceStack\Auth\JwtAuthProviderReader.cs:line 148
   at ExpressBase.ServiceStack.AppHost.Configure(Container container) in F:\ExpressBase\ExpressBase.Core\ExpressBase.ServiceStack\Startup.cs:line 94
   at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init() in F:\ExpressBase\ExpressBase.Core\ServiceStack.Core\ServiceStack\ServiceStackHost.cs:line 200
   at ServiceStack.NetCoreAppHostExtensions.UseServiceStack(IApplicationBuilder app, AppHostBase appHost) in F:\ExpressBase\ExpressBase.Core\ServiceStack.Core\ServiceStack\AppHostBase.NetCore.cs:line 224
   at ExpressBase.ServiceStack.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in F:\ExpressBase\ExpressBase.Core\ExpressBase.ServiceStack\Startup.cs:line 74}    System.PlatformNotSupportedException`

This is the line in our Startup.cs that is generating the Exception.

```
var jwtprovider = new MyJwtAuthProvider(AppSettings)
            {
                HashAlgorithm = "RS256",
                PrivateKeyXml = EbLiveSettings.PrivateKeyXml,
                PublicKeyXml = EbLiveSettings.PublicKeyXml,
                RequireSecureConnection = false,
                //EncryptPayload = true,
                CreatePayloadFilter = (payload, session) =>
                {
                    payload["sub"] = (session as CustomUserSession).UserAuthId;
                    payload["cid"] = (session as CustomUserSession).CId;
                    payload["uid"] = (session as CustomUserSession).Uid.ToString();
                    payload["wc"] = (session as CustomUserSession).WhichConsole;
                },
                ExpireTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromHours(10),
                ExpireRefreshTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromHours(12),
                PersistSession = true,
                SessionExpiry = TimeSpan.FromHours(12)
            };
```

The private and public key values are loaded from appsettings.json to EbLiveSettings.

The line in appsettings.json is

```
"JwtConfig": {
    "PublicKeyXml": "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>ip...7BfGi98ObWqKnD8o4pv....JQklgmblCs=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P></P><Q></Q><DP></DP><DQ></DQ><InverseQ></InverseQ><D></D></RSAKeyValue>",
    "PrivateKeyXml": "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>ip....lss7WqKnD8o4bKTp....IKbK2gaagCQ==</DP><DQ>BKOC....zlic+FQ==</DQ><InverseQ>JeIPWX....A==</InverseQ><D>iHU....cTrKeEGd</D></RSAKeyValue>"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you retry with the latest source code from master as I've restored some [RSA polyfills for .NET Core](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/47bd5f4c705bdce44543dabadaac2c26993af887).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, But the issue persists on the same line.

Comment: @AhammedUnniVP please update your question with the source code and configuration you’re using that can be used to repro it.

Comment: @AhammedUnniVP Should now be supported from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/a5bc5f5a96fb990b69dcad9dd5e95e688477fd94).

Comment: Thanks, @mythz, Now it is running perfectly. We are expecting to go beta by Jan 2018. When can we expect the next release of ServiceStack as we want to move to a release branch rather than the master?

Comment: @AhammedUnniVP We don’t provide ETAs, but before the end of the year.

Comment: Yes, the solution to write another version of FromXmlString works.  I only encountered this problem when I tried this utility as a console app using .NET core, whereas on a previous app using .NET framework this was never a problem.